# Ritalin for treating lack of focus in Major Depression Disorder

Tags: depression, psychologist-psychology, psychiatrist-psychiatry

I’d like to know if there’s research about the use of ritalin for treating attention deficit in Major Depression Disorder. I couldn’t find anything about it, so, I can’t indicate my previous reading on that topic. I just want to know if there is something about methylphenidate being used for treating attention impairment in depressive patients. Could you help me, please? 
Two link to my research. All articles are about ADHD and not about cognitive symptoms in depression and the use of ritalin combined with antidepressants.

https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?q=ritalin+for+treating+attention+deficit+in+depression&hl=pt-BR&as_sdt=0&as_vis=1&oi=scholart

https://scholar.google.com.br/scholar?start=10&q=ritalin+for+improving+attention+in+depression&hl=pt-BR&as_sdt=0,5&as_vis=1

Comment: Welcome to MedicalSciences.SE! Please take the [tour] and read the [help]. For [reasons mentioned in this post](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/q/411) and in [ask], we require prior research information when asking questions. *See [this list of helpful resources](https://medicalsciences.meta.stackexchange.com/a/784)*. Please help us to help you and [edit] your question to provide more information on what you have read on this subject, what made you ask this question, and any problems you are having understanding your research. If you found nothing, what did you Google?

Comment: @CareyGregory Edited. Take a look now, please

Comment: Your search criteria are flawed.  I found a bunch of articles using "methylphenidate in major depressive disorder" or "methylphenidate treatment depression."  Look for a recent meta analysis or literature review.

Comment: The pathophysiology of intattention in both conditions are different, but the research is interesting.